# Preserving a job running outside screen in an ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

Let's say I've ssh'd into my box and decided to run a long job, but have forgotten to run that job inside screen. Is there anything I can do to stop the job from terminating when the ssh session closes, after the job has already been started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can background ctrl-z the process so it will have a jobspec and then disown job spec. Then the job is no longer attached the terminal so when you exit the job continues.

Comment: I am assuming your shell is bash. If not something equivalent may still exist.

Comment: Yes it is, and thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.